# Please help me identify the passive form

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verb, passive, perfect-tense

What kind of the passive form is there in the following phrase, and where can I read more about it?

> ... unabhängig davon, wie diese Korrespondenz **aufgenommen worden sein mag** ...

Answer (score 1):

***Vorgangspassiv*** in **perfect tense** coupled with **a modal verb**. Compare:

> Die Dateien sollten wiederholt worden sein
>    ... dass der Saft von ihm getrunkenwordenseinkann.

A similar form with different meaning you may mistake it for is ***Zustandspassiv*** in Perfekt, coupled with a modal verb:

> unabhängig davon, wie diese Korrespondenz aufgenommen gewesen sein kann

A few examples for you: http://aktivaesperanto.org.es/apunts/Verbanalyse_Beispiele1.pdf

---

[To your question about grammar books on the subject.](https://books.google.de/books?id=SXC9_1FJ3KYC&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=modalverben%20%22worden%20sein%20kann%22)

Still, it's hard to recommend a source for you as we do not know your niveau. A general recommendation for most complicated grammatical questions is the Duden grammar.